# How can I query in firebase using angularFire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, nosql

I have a simple structure in Firebase:

```
{
  "categorias" : {
    "categoria2" : {
      "subcategorias" : {
        "subcategoria4" : {
          "nome" : "Subcategoria 4"
        },
        "subcategoria6" : {
          "nome" : "Subcategoria 6"
        },
        "subcategoria5" : {
          "nome" : "Subcategoria 5"
        }
      },
      "icone" : "fa-cloud",
      "nome" : "Categoria 2"
    },
    "categoria1" : {
      "subcategorias" : {
        "subcategoria1" : {
          "nome" : "Subcategoria 1"
        },
        "subcategoria3" : {
          "nome" : "Subcategoria 3"
        },
        "subcategoria2" : {
          "nome" : "Subcategoria 2"
        }
      },
      "icone" : "fa-bolt",
      "nome" : "Categoria 1"
    }
  },
  "locais" : {
    "local1" : {
      "subcategorias" : {
        "subcategoria4" : true,
        "subcategoria1" : true
      },
      "nome" : "Local 1",
      "email" : "local1@loc1.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to list all "locais" that have "subcateria1: true" for example. I don't know how to do this because it is need "localId" but in query I don't know the localId. I just want all the "locais" that belongs to subcategoria1.

I'm using AngularFire.

Comment: you can create references to parts of your data using angularfire's $child method and drill down from there https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#child-key

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what i need is a method to search in my "locais" and filter only the locais that have "subcateria1: true", i'm only do this with $child() if i know what "id" i need to iterate, but it's not the case.

Comment: Check out the Firebase blog, which [has a great article](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html) on converting from SQL queries to a Firebase mindset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, but i don't know if it is the right way:

```
findBySubcategoria: function(subcategoriaId) {                  
    var result = {};
    locais.$on("value", function(snap){
        var keys = snap.snapshot.value;

        angular.forEach(keys, function(key, i){                         
            if(key.subcategorias[subcategoriaId]){
                result[i] = locais.$child(i);
            }
        }); 

    });
    return result;
}
```